# Pearson correlation between two dataframes in python and output all combinations between columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Hello All I have two data frames with 3 columns and each of the rows from col1 has 82 different values from column variable and so as I have df2 with three same columns with different values for these three columns

df1.head()

```
    ID  variable value
0   ENSG3   AE02_ID 0.000001
1   ENSG1   AE02_ID 0.329180
2   ENSG8   AE02_ID 0.000000
3   ENSG10  AE02_ID 29.157761
4   ENSG20  AE02_ID 0.633884
```

and `df2.head()`

```
    Geneid  variable    value
0   ENSG60  AE02_ID 7.408430
1   ENSG53  AE02_ID 0.000000
2   ENSG94  AE02_ID 2.556464
3   ENSG49  AE02_ID 0.032384
4   ENSG9   AE02_ID 0.000000
```

I wanted to do a Pearson correlation on these two data frames, the output data frame should be with correlation coefficient from all possible combinations from both data frames. for instance something like this

```
ID1    ID2   coefficient
ENSG60 ENSG3 0.2
ENSG1 ENSG53  0.14
.
.
```

I tried with this one liner      `df1.value.corrwith(df2.value)`

But it's giving out only one coefficient with the corresponding

Comment: can you give your complete so that i can check? actually `corrwith` should work.

Comment: did you try `numpy.correlate`?

Comment: No, I haven't . And complete what ?

Comment: i am sorry, complete code!!

Comment: Actually, I tried in R and it works there ..but now I need to shift to python which I haven't done anything elaborate, whereas I just have a one liner as described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[pandas.DataFrame.corrwith](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.corrwith.html) should work for you. An alternative with [numpy.corrcoef](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.random(5), 'b': np.random.random(5)})
result = np.corrcoef(df1.a,df1.b)
print(result)
```

It outputs:

```
[[ 1.          0.02543264]
 [ 0.02543264  1.        ]]
```

Both `corrwith` and `corrcoef` are the same thing.

Comment: No, actually not this ..This gives me matrix of coefficients but I need something like, ID1    ID2   coefficient
ENSG60 ENSG3 0.2

Comment: Could please see my question now, I have shown what output I am excepting

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding, i have updated my code. please check.

Comment: It's a symmetric matrix so you coud do `result[0,1]` if you just want a single number.   Or also, `df1.a.corr(df1.b)`

Comment: Thanks for solutions but its still for one single dataframe I have two dataframe and each dataframe has different columns values and different shapes or dimension. So the above solution will not work for it.

Comment: Its just an example and i believe you can modify it to server your need.